# ReactJS can't load files in src

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in a file called index.html:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="src/Test2.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="asdf"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        class Test extends React.Component {
            render() {
                return (<h>asdf</h>);
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Test/>,
            document.getElementById('asdf')
        );

    </script>
</body>
```

I am trying to use code I've put in a file called Text2.js which is in a folder called src however I get the following error when I run the above code in chrome:

```
browser.js:5773 Failed to load file:///Users/.../src/Test2.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

PS: here is my folder structure:

```
../reactTutorial  
../reactTutorial/index.html  
../reactTutorial/src  
../reactTutorial/src/Test2.js
```

In case this is relavent I am on a mac, also here is the code in Text2.js:

```
var Test2 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>This is Test2</div>;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, First this is not ReactNative, it's ReactJS,
Second, seems you are trying to run the application without a http server, i mean you put the absolute path on your hard drive in the browser? right ?

Comment: yes thats right, sorry for the typo in the title. I am trying to open this in chrome like I said in the question like so: open index.html

Comment: show your folder tree here that is path issue

Comment: @fred as per Solaiman comment,you must create http server.Otherwisde host that Test2.js file on other server like CDN and include that path here

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: If you'd like to describe how to do that I'll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

create one http server will solve this issue.

Define `server.js` which run `http` server.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static('./src')) //assuming src folder will hold all assets.
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname) + '/index.html'))
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('app listening on port 3000!'))
```

**index.html**

add relative path to JS.exclude src `folder` name.

```
<script src="Test2.js"></script>
```

**Note :** install express.js

run it using **node server.js**

Answer (score 0):

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes
```

For chrome you have to host server(You can use nodejs server or gulp plugins). Try to open this in firefox - should be fine.

Comment: I tried that and it sort of worked, It no longer gives the error however once I exchange Test for Test2 right after "ReactDOM.render" I get the error "Test2 not defined"

Comment: @fred Try to launch page from incognito (ctrl+shift+N) or reload page by (ctrl+F5). If some of that works go to [F12->network->disable cache]. It's cache issues probably

Answer (score 0):

Better away is if you make this like this:
First: make this like react component example App.js and Test.js 
Second: import Test.js from App.js